# Drop Caps/Initial Caps on Heading that Wraps

Tags: css

I'm attempting to get a drop caps (or initial caps; whatever you may call it) effect on a heading. Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: example]

I've found success with inline span tags that are floated, but when the heading wraps into a second line, the paragraph section breaks onto its own line. See this jsfiddle for an example and adjust the viewing window to see the effect I'm referring to. http://jsfiddle.net/fEn4U/

The structure in the first two jsfiddle examples (with the `h1` and `p` tags) is how I would prefer to have the html. But I can settle for a `span` in the `p` tag if that's the only solution. As you can see, I'm further away from a solution with the h1, p structure than I am with the span and p tags.

Also note that the container will be a fixed width, and the content within will be dynamic, so I can't always rely on the heading breaking into two lines or staying on one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your small text `inline-block` and set a maximum size.

http://jsfiddle.net/fEn4U/2/

```
p {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really work for me. It assumes I know the width of the space between the second line of the header and the containing box when I don't. Like I said, the content will be dynamic, so if that blank space is ever smaller than 150px, or whatever I set the max-width at, the p block pushes to the next line, which I obviously don't want.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Here is an js solution http://jsfiddle.net/fEn4U/3/. Will try to experiment with pure css.